# How run component outside ssr angular 17

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, server-side-rendering

How can I run a component without ssr? For example, I need SSR only for the first page of the portal, for the others I don’t need it

```
server.get("/not-found", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(distFolder + "/index.html");
});
```